# Trying to Understand the Initialization of C++ STL Containers

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list

I am trying to understand the initialization of C++ STL containers. Here is the nightmare I got:

```
    vector<int> V0 ({ 10, 20 });    // ok - initialized with 2 elements
    vector<int> V1 = { 10, 20 };    // ok - initialized with 2 elements
    vector<int> V2 = {{ 10, 20 }};  // ok - initialized with 2 elements
    vector<int> V3 = {{ 10 }, 20 }; // ok - initialized with 2 elements
    vector<int> V4 { 10, 20 };      // ok - initialized with 2 elements
    vector<int> V5 {{ 10, 20 }};    // ok - initialized with 2 elements
    vector<int> V6 {{ 10 }, 20 };   // ok - initialized with 2 elements
    queue<int> Q0 ({ 10, 20 });     // ok - initialized with 2 elements
 // queue<int> Q1 = { 10, 20 };     // compile error
 // queue<int> Q2 = {{ 10, 20 }};   // compile error
 // queue<int> Q3 = {{ 10 }, 20 };  // compile error
 // queue<int> Q4 { 10, 20 };       // compile error
    queue<int> Q5 {{ 10, 20 }};     // ok - initialized with 2 elements
 // queue<int> Q6 {{ 10 }, 20 };    // compile error
```

We are talking about C++11.

I did some research, and here are my questions:

1. I believe the compile error is caused by the fact that `queue<T>`'s `initializer_list` constructor is missing. See `vector<T>`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/ and `queue<T>`:
   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/queue/ am I right?
2. Now for all the vectors from `V0` to `V6`, I understand `V0`, `V1`, `V4`. Can someone help me understand `V2`, `V3`, `V5` and `V6`?
3. I don't quite understand `Q0` or `Q5`. Can someone help me?

I am also reading Mike Lui's article: [Initialization in C++ is Seriously Bonkers](http://mikelui.io/2019/01/03/seriously-bonkers.html). I'd like to share it with you guys, but is there a quick way to help me understand this nightmare? :-)

Comment: I can understrike the _nightmare_. ;-) A counter example: `std::vector<int> V7(10, 20);` initializes `V7` with 10 elements: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cf5d84bde4ffec1).

Comment: @Scheff: That's the only "nightmare"ish issue, and it's not even one that the OP provides. All of the rest are just simple, standard list-initialization stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing "nightmarish" about any of that. You simply need to read what you've written. More specifically, you have to work through the rules from the outside in, systematically.

```
vector<int> V0 ({ 10, 20 });
```

Calls a `vector` constructor (that's what the `()` mean), passing it a single braced-init-list. Therefore, it will pick a constructor that takes one value, but only the constructor whose first parameter can be initialized by a 2-element braced-init-list containing integers. Such as the `initializer_list<int>` constructor that `vector<int>` contains.

```
vector<int> V1 = { 10, 20 };
```

List initialization (that's what happens when you initialize a thing with a braced-init-list directly). Under list-initialization rules, all constructors of the type which take a single `initializer_list` parameter are considered first. The system attempts to initializer these constructors with the braced-init-list directly; if it can succeed with one of the candidate constructors, then that constructor is called.

Obviously, you can initialize an `initializer_list<int>` from a 2-element braced-init-list of integers. And this is the only `initializer_list` constructor in `vector`, so it gets called.

```
vector<int> V2 = {{ 10, 20 }};
```

Still list initialization. Again, `initializer_list` constructors which match the values in the braced-init-list are considered. However, the "value" in the braced-init-list is itself another braced-init-list. `int` cannot be initialized from a 2-element braced-init-list, so the `initializer_list<int>` cannot be initialized by `{{10, 20}}`.

Since no `initializer_list` constructor can be used, *all* constructors are considered under normal function overload resolution rules. In this case, the members of the (outer) braced-init-list are considered arguments to the constructors of the type. There is only one value in the outer braced-init-list, so only constructors which can be called with one argument are considered.

The system will attempt to initialize the first parameter of all such constructors with the inner braced-init-list. And there is a constructor whose parameter can be initialized by a 2-element braced-init-list of integers. Namely, the `initializer_list<int>` constructor. That is, while `initializer_list<int>` can't be initialized by `{{10, 20}}`, it can be initialized by just `{10, 20}`.

```
vector<int> V3 = {{ 10 }, 20 };
```

Again, still list initialization. So again, we first attempt to apply the full braced-init-list to any `initializer_list` constructors of the type. Can `initializer_list<int>` be initialized from a braced-init-list of `{{10}, 20}`? Yes. So that's what happens.

Why does this work? Because any type `T` which is copyable/moveable can always be initialized from a braced-init-list containing some value of that type. That is, if `T t = some_val;` works, then so too does `T t = {some_val};` (unless `T` has an `initializer_list` constructor that takes `T`, which would be decidedly weird). And if `T t = {some_val};` works, then so too does `initializer_list<T> il = {{some_val}};`.

```
vector<int> V4 { 10, 20 };      // ok - initialized with 2 elements
vector<int> V5 {{ 10, 20 }};    // ok - initialized with 2 elements
vector<int> V6 {{ 10 }, 20 };   // ok - initialized with 2 elements
```

These are identical to 1, 2, and 3. List initialization is often called "uniform initialization" because there is (almost) no difference between using the braced-init-list directly and using `= braced-init-list`. The only times there is a difference is if an explicit constructor is selected or if you're using `auto` with a single value in the braced-init-list.

---

`queue`s `initializer_list` constructor is not "missing". It doesn't exist on purpose because `queue` is not a *container*. It is a container *adapter* type. It stores a container and adapts the container's interface to be restricted to queue operations: push, pop, and peek.

So none of those are *supposed* to work.

```
queue<int> Q0 ({ 10, 20 });
```

This calls a constructor of `queue<int>` using regular old overload resolution, just like `V0`. The only difference is that the constructor it selects is the one that takes the container type for the queue. Since you didn't specify a container, it uses the default: `std::deque<int>`, which can be constructed from a braced-init-list of two integers.

```
queue<int> Q5 {{ 10, 20 }};
```

Same situation as `V2`. There are no initializer_list constructors on `queue`, so it acts exactly like `Q0`: using overload resolution to select a constructor whose argument can take a braced-init-list of 2 integers.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the answer a bit with examples, so it can help new bee's like me

Comment: @TruthSeeker: With examples of what? "new bee's" shouldn't really be looking too deeply into this stuff to begin with. If you want to initialize a container, you should just use `V1` and move on.

Comment: Thanks @NicolBolas. Really appreciated. The explanation is great, though I still spent hours understanding it. The reason I was asking this question is because I found that nowadays the C++ language is becoming so difficult to understand (I used to be pride of "knowing C++").
I was even thinking what if the value type is a `pair<int, int>` instead of a pure `int`? :-) It will become so confusing that, it will take a lot of time to understand even for a sophisticated C++ expert.